# WelcomeBot - a bot to welcome you

Tags: app, chat, chatbot

## WelcomeBot

A Stack Exchange chatbot written in Python that uses [ChatExchange](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange). Many parts of this were modeled after [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector), another Stack Exchange chatbot.

---

### Features

- Welcomes new users entering chatrooms on [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com), [chat.meta.stackexchange](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com), and [chat.stackoverflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) with a custom welcome command made by you
- Many different chatroom commands:

  - `//image (image search term)` - searches for and posts images of or relating to the image search term
  - `//search (search term)` - finds the top three results on google and posts them
  - `//choose (choice) or (choice) [or choice...]` - makes decisions for you so you don't have to. Can accept more than two choices as long as they are separated by `or`
  - `//weather (city)[, country/state]` - gets the weather for whatever location you would like
  - `//youtube (youtube search term)` - search [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/) for and returns a video of or relating to your search term
  - `//source` - gives you a link to WelcomeBot's source code on Github
  - `//info` - tells you the host site, room id, and welcome message
  - `//help` - tells you all of the commands listed above in case you forget
- Commands for privileged users:

  - `//die` - kills the bot if it is acting up
  - `//reset` - resets the bot just in case
  - `//pull` - updates the bot with the latest commit on Github
  - `//pause` - pauses the bot temporarily
  - `//start` - resumes the bot when it is paused
  - `//editmsg [new welcome message]` - edit the welcome message
  - `//priv [user id]` - gives a user the ability to use this command and the six commands listed above

---

### Setup

In all cases, you are supposed to have [Git](http://git-scm.com/) installed, as well as
[pip Python package manager](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip).

#### Linux

Run `setup.sh`:

```
dev@welcomebot$ ./setup.sh
Setting up WelcomeBot.
Cloning WelcomeBot...
Cloning into 'michaelpri10/WelcomeBot'...
Submodule 'ChatExchange' (https://github.com/michaelpri10/ChatExchange.git) registered for path 'ChatExchange'
Cloning into 'ChatExchange'...
Submodule path 'ChatExchange': checked out '...'
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.4.0
Successfully installed requests-2.7.0
Successfully installed websocket-client-0.32.0
Setup completed.

dev@welcomebot$ ./setup.sh --help
Set up WelcomeBot.

Usage:
  ./setup.sh [--help | --no-clone]

Options:
  --help      Print this help message and exit
  --no-clone  Do NOT clone a WelcomeBot git repo (default behavior when inside a repo)
```

You can obtain our `setup.sh` from our [Releases](https://github.com/michaelpri10/WelcomeBot/releases)
list on GitHub; in that case, it will try to clone and install the WelcomeBot version it was released for.

Otherwise you can `git clone` the latest development version of WelcomeBot source code from GitHub
yourself and then run `setup.sh` included in repository.

#### Windows

On Windows, installation is not so straightforward. You first have to clone WelcomeBot source code yourself:

```
C:\Users\WelcomeBot> git clone https://github.com/michaelpri10/WelcomeBot.git
Cloning into 'WelcomeBot'...
C:\Users\WelcomeBot> cd WelcomeBot
```

And then run `setup.bat` included in repository:

```
C:\Users\WelcomeBot\WelcomeBot> .\setup.bat
```

---

To run WelcomeBot, run `nocrash.sh` and log in with your Stack Exchange OpenID credentials.

---

### Why use WelcomeBot?

- Make new users feel welcome in your chatroom
- Have fun in your chatroom

---

### Source Code

- WelcomeBot is an open source project and all of its code is available on [Github.](https://github.com/michaelpri10/WelcomeBot)
- WelcomeBot is constantly being updated; luckily the `//pull` commands makes it easy to keep up
- If you want to see WelcomeBot in action check out the [Teenage Programmers Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22091/teenage-programmers-chatroom), the current home for WelcomeBot
- WelcomeBot was created by michaelpri ([Github](https://github.com/michaelpri10), [Stack Exhange](http://stackexchange.com/users/4642421/michaelpri)), ProgramFOX ([Github](https://github.com/programfox), [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/3094403/programfox)), and Jacob Gray ([Github](https://github.com/Jacob-Gray), [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/3984803/jacob-gray))

Comment: How do you set the welcome command? (Oh, and I think you meant *git sub**m**odule update*.)

Comment: @zondo I've update the post, everything should be there now. You can use `//editmsg` to change the welcome message